# ASP DataAnnotations DisplayFormat using substring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, string-formatting, data-annotations

I have a string in which I want to only display from 4th character to the end of the string. For example, I would like to display the following in my view:

```
MyLogin
```

When the string is in this format:

```
string Login = "RDN\MyLogin";
```

I want to do something like this:

```
public partial class MyLogin
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = Login.Substring(3, Login.Length);)]
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

How can I accomplish something like this?

Comment: You cannot. The values in attributes must be constants, not something that is evaluated at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this was not the solution I was looking for I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

In my Model

```
public partial class MyLogin
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public virtual String getUser()
    {
        return Login.Substring(4, Login.Length - 4);
    }
}
```

In my view

```
@foreach (var login in Model)                    
{
  <tr>             
     <td>@{ var user = login.getUser();}@user</td>
  </tr>
}
```